# Porting strategy pattern from SQL Server to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

SQL Server has a feature whereby you can call a function or stored procedure with a variable name for the func/proc name.  Toy example:

```
declare @name sysname;
declare @method int = 1;
set @name = IIF(@method = 1, N'Newton', N'Taylor')
declare @sqrt float;
exec @sqrt = @name 42
```

This will call either Newton or Taylor depending on the value of @method.  Using this, it is possible to implement the strategy or command OOP patterns in T-SQL.  Where I work, we use it for just that purpose.

Now that I'm learning Postgresql, I'm wondering how I would do something similar in pgplsql.  Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all called functions return a single value of the same data type and take a single parameter of the same data type, you can do that with dynamic SQL in Postgres as well:

```
create or replace function evaluate(p_input integer, p_method text)
  returns float
as
$$
declare
  l_result float;
begin
  execute 'select '||p_method||'($1)' 
     using p_input 
     into l_result;
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

- `select evaluate(42, 'sqrt');` returns 6.48074069840786
- `select evaluate(1, 'exp');` returns 2.718281828459045

---

This works with multiple parameters as well:

```
create or replace function evaluate(p_arg_1 integer, p_arg_2 text, p_method text)
  returns float
as
$$
declare
  l_result float;
begin
  execute 'select '||p_method||'($1, $2)' 
     using p_arg_1, p_arg_2 
     into l_result;
  return l_result;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Nice! Can that approach work with more than one arg?

Comment: @user1443098: as long as all called functions accept multiple arguments, yes.

Comment: perfect for strategy pattern.  I'll take it